# How to Change Variable in embed TableVeiw in ContainerView? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

```
class MyView:UIViewController{


         override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            print(segue.destination)
            let distinationVC = segue.destination as? MyTableController
            distinationVC?.topConstaints.constant = 0


         }
}
class MyTableController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var topConstaints: NSLayoutConstraint!

}
```

return

```
 print(segue.destination)

<myApp. MyTableController:0 x>
```

but raise exception in

```
distinationVC?.topConstaints.constant = 0

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

i don't know how to fix this

Comment: check if the topConstaints outlet is properly connected

Comment: your topConstaints property is nil. set this property in MyTableController's viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `topConstaints` in `prepare(for segue:)` won't work because the controller view has not been created yet.

Either create a `CGFloat` variable in `MyTableController` then change your `topConstaints` in `viewDidLoad` or call `let _ = distinationVC.view` right after `let distinationVC = ..` to trigger distinationVC's `loadView`.